# At least one eigenvalue among all roots

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space and $f \in \text{End}V$. Let $p$ be a polynomial over a field $K$ so that $p(f)=0$. Also we have deg $p = m$ and $c_1,c_2,\dots,c_m$ be all roots of $p$. Prove that at least one $c_i$ is an eigenvalue of $f$.

So if $c_i$ are all roots we can conclude that
$$
p(x) = k(x-c_1)\dots(x-c_m)
$$
If we substitute $f$ for $x$ then we get
$$
p(f) = k(f - c_1)\circ\dots\circ(f-c_m) = 0
$$
How to proceed from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $p(x)=k(x-c_1)^{\alpha_1}\cdots(x-c_m)^{\alpha_m}$ for some $k\in K\setminus\{0\}$ and some natural $\alpha_j$'s (you can't conclude that the $\alpha_j$'s are equal to $1$). And$$p(f)=0\iff k(f-c_1\operatorname{Id})^{\alpha_1}\circ\cdots\circ(f-c_m\operatorname{Id})^{\alpha_m}=0.$$But then *some* $f-c_k\operatorname{Id}$ is not invertible and therefore $c_k$ is an eigenvalue of $f$.

Comment: If we have $m$ distinct roots, don't we have $\alpha_j=1$? How can we conclude that (f-c_k) isn't invertible?

Comment: I missed the fact that there are as many roots as the degree of the polynomial. But that's a useless hypothesis anyway. And if you compose invertible maps, what you get is again an invertible map. But the null function is *not* invertible. So…